# How to get the value from a "key = value" string from a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Given a file with content of the following form:

```
// This is a comment
FOO = 1
BAR = 0
// Comments can be anywhere...
BAZ = 10 //...even here!
```

The keys will always be anchored to the start of a line, but there may be any number of spaces on either side of the '`=`' character. The value may also be trailed by any number of spaces.

EDIT: The value and/or its trailing spaces may also be followed by a comment.

How can I get a key's value as a one-liner using `bash` scripting and/or `awk` or `sed`? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
MYVAL=$(<string manipulation to get value of "BAZ" from /tmp/foo.txt>)
```

to arrive at

```
>echo $MYVAL
10
>
```

I'm pretty terrible at bash scripting; never got fluent enough with the suite of string manipulation tools to know how to approach this. The furthest I could get was

```
> grep BAZ /tmp/foo.txt
BAZ = 10
```

and didn't really know what to do next.

I did search around SO, but couldn't find a solution with quite the same premise (specifically, the presence of a variable number of spaces on either side of the '`=`'), and the solutions to *similar* questions did not work in my premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-line solution with `sed`:

```
MYVAR=$(sed -nE 's/^BAZ\s*=\s*(\S*)$/\1/p' inputfile)
```

As noted in one comment, this `sed` command will not produce desired result in the following scenario:

```
BAZ = 10 // some comment ending with 0
```

Here `MYVAR` will be assigned `0` instead of `10`. To fix this problem the regex can be changed to:

```
MYVAR=$(sed -nE 's/^BAZ\s*=\s*([^\s\/]*).*/\1/p' inputfile)
```

Now `MYVAR` is `10` as needed. Breaking apart the regular expression:

```
^BAZ\s*=\s*([^\s\/]*).*/\1
^                           Match beginning of line
 BAZ                        Match BAZ
    \s*=\s*                 Match equal sign surrounded by zero or more spaces
           ([^\s\/]*)       Capture in Group 1 any character that is not space or slash
                     .*     Match the rest of the text
                       /\1  Replace matched text with text in Group 1
```

Comment: As of the first revision, this doesn't work when I test it. See https://ideone.com/LvtgjA -- the comments, as well as `FOO` and `BAR`, are still there in the output.

Comment: I was testing with different options, and forgot to add `-n` in my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: Better, yes. If we take the OP at their word that comments can appear *anywhere*, then I assume `BAZ=0 // explanation of why baz is 0` should keep that comment out of the value -- but then, the example is ambiguous on that point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - you're correct in that `//` may appear the way you noted.

Comment: @StoneThrow, see if your `sed` supports `-r` instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thank you: "`-nr`" in place of the flags that @Sergio noted gives a desired result. I'd be grateful if anyone could explain how this works, I would like to at least make an effort to improve my bash string manipulation skills.

Comment: `-E` or `-r` enable ERE, as opposed to BRE, regular expression syntax. (BTW, I'd tend to suggest `[[:space:]]` rather than `\s`, which is not guaranteed to be available in either).

Comment: ...btw, as a starting point for learning about bash string manipulation in general, I'd suggest [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Answer (score 0):

One easy answer is to use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to strip unwanted whitespace. The following should look very much like the answers on similar questions you considered:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Requires bash 4.0" >&2; exit 1;; esac

shopt -s extglob                     # make *([[:space:]]) mean "zero-or-more spaces"
declare -A array=( )

while read -r line; do
  line=${line%%*([[:space:]])"//"*}  # trim everything after the first "//" in the line
  [[ $line = *=* ]] || continue      # skip lines without an "=" after this is done
  key=${line%%*([[:space:]])=*}      # key is everything before the first "=" & whitespace
  value=${line#*=}                   # value is everything after the first "="
  value=${value##+([[:space:]])}     # remove leading spaces from value
  array[$key]=$value
done

# print result to stderr
declare -p array >&2
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/UwYs3C, having for the input given in the question the following result:

```
declare -A array=([FOO]="1" [BAR]="0" [BAZ]="10" )
```

...thus, one could `echo "Read value for foo as ${array[FOO]}"` to emit `Read value for foo as 1`.

Comment: Is there not a "one-liner" that can solve the problem? I dwell on this because one of my must-satisfy reviewers will balk at anything else (they're not really a source I can turn to for advice)

Comment: Terseness is all-too-often achieved by making tradeoffs against correctness, robustness, readability, maintainability, portability, etc. As such, all I can offer is a raised eyebrow regarding said "must-satisfy" reviewer's qualifications for the role.

Comment: We could have a LOOONG discussion about the person-of-note. :) In the meanwhile, thank you for your modification to Sergio's answer. It appears to work with a simple test; I'll see how robust it is otherwise.